# How to configure grunt-protractor-runner / protractor / selenium-webdriver to configure firefox 56 to accept all SSL certs

Tags: angular, selenium, firefox, protractor

I have an angular webapp which is becoming a PWA. So, it has a ServiceWorker. And, so, it requires a valid https session (or an exception on the certificate presenter by the server).

It also has automatic E2E tests, with protractor.

I do not find how to get them running with firefox (chrome is ok), with a server running on localhost and listening on port 8447.

I am failing to convince the instance of firefox launched by protractor through selenium-webdriver to accept all SSL certs, or even only the cert used by this test server.

I am using firefox driver in "directConnect" mode.

I am using grunt because I have to launch a few things before and after the E2E tests.

In my Gruntfile.js, my protractor / firefox session is :

```
grunt.initConfig({
    protractor: {
        firefox: {
            options: {
                keepAlive: true,
                configFile: "test/conf.firefox.js"
            },
            run: {}
        },
        ...
    },...
});
```

In test/conf.firefox.js, I have :

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    directConnect: true,
    specs: ['delegations.js'],
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'acceptSSlCerts': true
    },
    webDriverProxy: null,
    verbose: true,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        isVerbose: true,
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
    maxSessions: 1,
    params: {
            url: 'https://localhost:8447/mywebapp'
    }
}
```

I tried accepSslCerts along with a lot of other options, with no success.
Does someone have a clue ? I was all ok before with firefox 53 and protractor 4.x.

I am using :

- grunt-protractor-runner 5.0.0
- protractor 5.0.0
- selenium-webdriver 3.6.0
- firefox 56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capability was renamed in [Selenium 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#capabilities) to `acceptInsecureCerts`:

```javascript
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    directConnect: true,
    specs: ['delegations.js'],
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
        'acceptInsecureCerts': true
    },
```